# format all textfields the same in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield

I'm trying to learn Flutter. I have the below TextField setup as I would like it, I could copy and paste all the settings/properties for each TextField in the app, however is there a better way to make all of the TextFields have the same setting/properties?

```
    Flexible(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: TextField(
            maxLength: 5,
            maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true, signed: false, ),
            inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[0-9.]"))],
            //keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ),
              floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.center,
              //border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
              ),
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              labelText: 'Empty Weight',
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.grey[350],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course and basically, this is the main idea behind Flutter - you are building reusable components (widgets) and later use them to build your app.

1. Identify what properties of your `TextField` should change. E.g. let's consider (from your example) that could be `labelText` and `maxLength`.
2. Create a custom Widget that wraps the `TextField` and defines the extracted properties as Widget properties and use them as variables for the `TextField`:

```
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String labelText;
  final int maxLength;

  const CustomTextField({
    required this.labelText,
    required this.maxLength,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      maxLength: maxLength,
      maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
        decimal: true,
        signed: false,
      ),
      inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[0-9.]"))],
      //keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.center,
        //border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
        ),
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        labelText: labelText,
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.grey[350],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

3. User your `CustomTextField` in the code:

```
Flexible(
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: CustomTextField(
      maxLength: 5,
      labelText: 'Empty Weight',
    ),
  ),
);
```